# Why do we define vector spaces over fields and not over commutative rings with unity?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am using commutative ring with unity in the sense that there exists at least one non-zero element in the ring which doesn't have a multiplicative inverse. Can't we define scalar multiplication on a vector space with elements of commutative ring with unity, instead of field?

Comment: Yes we can, but it has slightly different properties, and is called a *module* over the ring.

Comment: Yes we can. But some things break down. For example we cannot prove that $a\cdot x=0$ implies that either $x=0$ or $a=0$ because we can no longer multiply by $1/a$. This has implications elsewhere. For example, a non-zero vector need not form a linearly independent set. Consequently the concepts of basis and dimension need modifications, and won't play out as nicely as they do over a field. You cannot necessarily find linearly independent sets of generators (even assuming a finite generator set).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can do that. We just don't call them “vector spaces”. We call them “[modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics))” instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could, but there a lot of things you couldn't do with them, for instance normalization.

Comment: You can't always normalize over fields either. Consider $(1, 1)\in \Bbb Q^2$. And some vector spaces don't even _have_ norms (although it's often possible to _construct_ one).

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a commutative unital ring, then an $R$-module is an abelian group $M$ with a "scalar multiplication" map $R \times M \to M$, written $r \cdot m = rm$, which satisfies

1. $(r + s)m = rm + sm$
2. $r(m + n) = rm + rn$
3. $r(sm) = (rs)m$

If $R$ is a field, then an $R$-module is precisely a vector space over that field, and we get the usual notions of dimension, bases, and so on. However, if $R$ is not a field, then an $R$-module is usually a slightly more complicated thing.

For example if $R = \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}^2, \ldots$ are all $\mathbb{Z}$-modules in the usual way, and any basis of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ will have size $n$. However, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is also a $\mathbb{Z}-module$, and it has no basis. (No element $m$ of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is linearly independent, since $3m = 0$). So the theory of modules is more complicated than the theory of vector spaces.